# When can I enable JQueryUI drag-and-drop in my AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have an AngularJS app that's a table of users. It's generated with this code:

```
<tr class="userRow" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'last_name'">
    <td><div class="userIcon"><img src="{{user.user_icon}}" /></div></td>
    <td>{{user.user_id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

My `$scope.users` model is loaded asynchronously, so the table of users appears slightly after the DOM is loaded. After it's loaded, I'm using `$rootScope` and broadcasting a `usersLoaded` event, which is being caught by my classes app.

My classes app is a group of tables with slots in them. So the idea is that you could drag a user's icon into a slot in the class, and I'd handle the rest from there.

I'm catching the broadcasted event fine, and calling `$('.userIcon').draggable()` after the data's loaded. But I think I might be calling it too soon. I guess there's a slight delay between when the data's loaded and when the DOM updates.

So I guess I'm asking if there's a separate event that Angular would fire after the view is updated? I tried listening for `'$viewContentLoaded'`, but that didn't seem to fire.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Here's my current PlaceUsers controller code:

```
/**
* Place users in groups
 */
 function PlaceUsers($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.classes = [
        {slots: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},
        {slots : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
    ];

    $scope.addEvents = function(){
        console.log('adding events');
        $(".userIcon").draggable({
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            cursorAt: {top: 15, left:15},
            snap: '.slot', 
            snapMode: 'inner'
        });
        $(".slot").droppable({
            accept: ".userIcon",
            activeClass: 'ui-state-active',
            hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover'
        });
    }
    $scope.$on('usersLoaded', $scope.addEvents);
    $scope.$evalAsync('$viewContentLoaded', $scope.addEvents);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Instead of watching custom event, create directive that would call `.draggable()` on icon during linking stage. This way guaranties that the users are already loaded. Sort of like this:

```
.directive("userIcon", function () {
    function link (scope, el, attr) {
        el.draggable();
    }
    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: "C"
    }
});
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/EkUlosUg/2/edit).